# How to save the accent character é as Ã© in a mysql database when it is inserted in a form in Symfony2 ?

Tags: database, forms, symfony, save, special-characters

I would like to know how to save the accent character é as Ã© in a mysql database when it is inserted in a form in Symfony2. The explanation is as below:

This the code of the form builder I have:

```
    <?php

namespace Ikproj\GroupeBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class MessagesType extends AbstractType
{
     /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('contenu','textarea', array('attr' => array('rows' => '6','cols' => '40')));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Ikproj\GroupeBundle\Entity\Messages'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ikproj_groupebundle_messages';
    }
}
```

This is the code of the entity belonged to the form builder above:

```
    <?php

namespace Ikproj\GroupeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Messages
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="messages")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ikproj\GroupeBundle\Entity\MessagesRepository")
 */
class Messages
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer 
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="actor", type="integer")
     */
     private $actor;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="subject", type="integer")
     */
    private $subject;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="contenu", type="string")
     */
    private $contenu;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set actor
     *
     * @param integer $actor
     * @return Messages
     */
    public function setActor($actor)
    {
        $this->actor = $actor;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get actor
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getActor()
    {
        return $this->actor;
    }

    /**
     * Set subject
     *
     * @param integer $subject
     * @return Messages
     */
    public function setSubject($subject)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get subject
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getSubject()
    {
        return $this->subject;
    }

    /**
     * Set contenu
     *
     * @param string $contenu
     * @return Messages
     */
    public function setContenu($contenu)
    {
        $this->contenu = $contenu;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get contenu
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContenu()
    {
        return $this->contenu;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param string $status
     * @return Messages
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return Messages
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }
}
```

This is the code of the controller I have:

```
 public function SendMessageAction(Request $request, $actor, $subject, $cible) {
        $message = new Messages();
        $form = $this->createForm(new MessagesType(), $message);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $actor1 = $actor;
        $subject1 = $subject;
        $status1 = "unseen";
        $cible1 = $cible;
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $message->setActor($actor1);
                $message->setSubject($subject1);
                $message->setStatus($status1);
                $message->setType($cible1);
                $em->persist($message);
                $em->flush();
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
            }
        } 
        else {
            return $this->render('IkprojGroupeBundle:Messages:SendMessage.html.twig', array(
                        'form' => $form->createView(),
                        'actor' => $actor,
                        'subject' => $subject,
                        'cible' => $cible
            ));
        }
    }
```

And this is the code of the file config.yml belonged to the doctrine configuration:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   "%database_driver%"
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
```

The problem is that when I insert the accent character é in the form then I valid, it will be saved in the database as é not Ã© as you can see in screenshot below:

[image]

Whereas when I run the code below in Symfony2:

```
 <?php
$tab = $_REQUEST['table'];
$a = $tab[0];
$b = $tab[1];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","wkayetdb");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO messages(actor,subject,contenu,status,type) VALUES ($a,$b,'é','unseen','G')");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

it works correctly and the character é will be saved as Ã© as you can see below:

[image]

So, my questions are:

1. What is wrong in my code?
2. How can I save é as Ã© in a mysql database once it is inserted in a form in Symfony2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why you want to do that
but if you want to do this, simply comment that line "charset:  UTF8"

```
doctrine:
 dbal:
    driver:   "%database_driver%"
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
#    charset:  UTF8
```